# JSON Searches on sub arrays

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

```
{
  "name": "testcase #1",
  "words": [
    "the",
    "quick",
    "brown",
    "fox",
    "jump",
    "over",
    "the",
    "lazy",
    "dog"
  ],
  "values": [
    1,
    1,
    4,
    4,
    1,
    6,
    1,
    3,
    5
  ]
},
{
  "name": "testcase #2",
  "words": [
    "the",
    "second",
    "test",
    "about",
    "jump",
    "over",
    "the",
    "lazy",
    "dog"
  ],
  "values": [
    3,
    2,
    4,
    5,
    3,
    6,
    4,
    3,
    1
  ]
}
```

How would I formulate a query in dynamoDb to search for all records that a certain "words" has is in the range of certain values.
for the example record above it would match any of teh following and return the whole matching record.

```
"the" < 2
"the" = 1
"brown" > 3
```

I could also ask to return all "words" which value is less than 3 would return;

```
"the", "quick", "second", "dog"
```

Ive search around but could not find a clear documentation on how to do this without having to scan the whole table which could have a major performance and cost impact.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Actually not much, i have no clue where to start...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with the above structure provided in the post, it is **not feasible** to to form the filter expression.

**Proposed change in data model:-**

Store the `words` attribute as `map` DynamoDB data type.

**Example:-**

[image: Storing words as map]

**Query:-**

Please note that if you want to use DynamoDB **Query API**, you must have HASH Key data. If you don't have hash key data, you need to use **Scan API** or need **GSI** (Global Secondary Index).

**Example query expression to filter the data by words count:-**

Please note that I have used the hash key value 'testcase 1' in `KeyConditionExpression` and other attributes on `FilterExpression`.

If you don't have hash key, you need to use Scan API.

```
var table = "testcase";

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : '#name = :hkey',
    FilterExpression: 'words.the < :wordval1 and words.the = :wordval2 and  words.brown > :wordval3',
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        '#name' : 'name'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':hkey' : 'testcase 1',
        ':wordval1' : 2,
        ':wordval2' : 1,
        ':wordval3' : 3
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you I will study your solution. The actual whole structure is much more complex but that will give me a good starting point.  I might come back with more questions once I look at it.

Comment: Actually that might not work as, in the above example, the word "the" should be duplicated with possibly different numeric value associated. In the whole structure, I have also more informations associated to each words which is not displayed here but exist in the big structure.